# Scrollbar hit area is too small on OS X

Tags: macos, scrolling

Here is a zoomed screenshot of a terminal window corner with lots of output. I marked with a red paint an actual area I need to click to drag the scroolbar, anything below or to the right from that will trigger window resize instead which is extremely annoying. Are there any solutions to this?

[image]

Comment: Why not use the mouse wheel?

Comment: @Daniel Because it's slow, I can drag the scrollbar through the 1000s of lines of output instantly, I would need to keep scrolling for a few minutes for a similar result (or clicking and holding above the scroolbar which will also scroll only one screen at a time).

Comment: 10.8, 10.9?  Sorry I can't tell.

Comment: @Everett 10.9, though I think this problem was there for a long time (it's not just in terminal, any window). Eclipse IDE looks like is adding extra 20px gap between scroolbars and window edges to battle this.